# EF Core query for one-to-one relations using method syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have 3 tables `Applications`, `Systems`, `Databases`. System can have multiple applications but 0-1 databases. Because of Entity Framework database-first approach, there is no database property in our system class.

I have the following LINQ query (simplified) that works perfectly fine, creates join to databases table and retrieves version property:

```
var query  = from app in ctx.Apps
             join sys in ctx.Systems on app.SystemId equals sys.SystemId
             join db in ctx.Databases on db.SystemId equals sys.SystemId into dbAt
             from dbAlias  in dbAt.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where ..
             select ApplicationDto {
              ...
               DatabaseVersion = (dbAlias == null ? null : dbAlias.Version)
              ...
              };
```

I am in the process of rewriting every query from Linq syntax to method syntax but this one seems impossible to figure out. I can't use `.IncludeThen(x => x.System.Database)` cause `System` doesn't have a `Database` property.

Is it possible to join on alias (`Database` type) that can be accessed in select as I did in LINQ? I don't want to add `Database` class to `System` because it will probably be removed after next run of

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
```

Comment: Why do you say "Because of Entity-Framework DatabaseFirst approach there is no Database property in our System class" ? The foreign key of Database in the System class could be defined as nullable.

Comment: I mean't it wasn't created by dbcontext scaffold command and I am afraid any manual changes in model will be overwritten after next scaffold. Are you saying I should add nullable Database property and let EF figure out how to create joins  with my .IncludeThen() ?

Comment: None of what you are talking about seems related to method syntax, nor is it in your current query. You can do joins with method syntax using the `IQueryable.Join` method in the exact same way. If you want to use navigation properties (which you can do in query syntax), you need to have them built in your model.

Comment: The query in my example works without having neither database property in System class nor system property in Database class. I just wonder if (and how) similar thing can be done in method syntax without updating my model.